# Cant ORDER BY or in a DESC order MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I hope I'm not being to pushy, I tried using SQLYog and some other app for query building but let's face it, nothing beats the expertise of all of you. So here is I my question:
Is it possible to order the results of this query in a manner that it's order by the most viewed (vistas.cuenta) And DESC?, You see vistas(viewed) is the table where php-mysql stored the amount of time an article is viewed (on a column named cuenta(count)), right now it's working but it presents them in the order of the Union. On the vistas table I have stores the ID of the article and a column that holds the table name for each table.

In a two table scenarios it would be.

```
SELECT ciencia.id,ciencia.titulo,vistas.cuenta
FROM vistas, ciencia
WHERE vistas.id_pag = ciencia.id
AND vistas.seccion = ciencia.tabla
ORDER BY vistas.cuenta
```

That (the query up there) works perfect, but it doesn't work for the query below.

```
include("connection.php");
$data = "
SELECT ciencia.id,ciencia.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, ciencia WHERE vistas.id_pag = ciencia.id AND vistas.seccion = ciencia.tabla
UNION  SELECT cultura.id,cultura.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, cultura WHERE vistas.id_pag = cultura.id AND vistas.seccion = cultura.tabla
UNION  SELECT deportes.id,deportes.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, deportes WHERE vistas.id_pag = deportes.id AND vistas.seccion = deportes.tabla
UNION  SELECT economia.id,economia.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, economia WHERE vistas.id_pag = economia.id AND vistas.seccion = economia.tabla
UNION  SELECT internacionales.id,internacionales.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, internacionales WHERE vistas.id_pag = internacionales.id AND vistas.seccion = internacionales.tabla
UNION  SELECT migracion.id,migracion.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, migracion WHERE vistas.id_pag = migracion.id AND vistas.seccion = migracion.tabla
UNION  SELECT nacionales.id,nacionales.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, nacionales WHERE vistas.id_pag = nacionales.id AND vistas.seccion = nacionales.tabla
UNION  SELECT regionales.id,regionales.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, regionales WHERE vistas.id_pag = regionales.id AND vistas.seccion = regionales.tabla
UNION  SELECT politica.id,politica.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, politica WHERE vistas.id_pag = politica.id AND vistas.seccion = politica.tabla
";
$extractor = $mon -> query($data);
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $extractor ))
{ print $fila['id'].' seccion '.$fila['titulo'].' - '.$fila['cuenta'].'<br>'; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just wrap your query into another `SELECT` and order the result:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(SELECT ciencia.id,ciencia.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, ciencia WHERE vistas.id_pag = ciencia.id AND vistas.seccion = ciencia.tabla
UNION  SELECT cultura.id,cultura.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, cultura WHERE vistas.id_pag = cultura.id AND vistas.seccion = cultura.tabla
UNION  SELECT deportes.id,deportes.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, deportes WHERE vistas.id_pag = deportes.id AND vistas.seccion = deportes.tabla
UNION  SELECT economia.id,economia.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, economia WHERE vistas.id_pag = economia.id AND vistas.seccion = economia.tabla
UNION  SELECT internacionales.id,internacionales.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, internacionales WHERE vistas.id_pag = internacionales.id AND vistas.seccion = internacionales.tabla
UNION  SELECT migracion.id,migracion.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, migracion WHERE vistas.id_pag = migracion.id AND vistas.seccion = migracion.tabla
UNION  SELECT nacionales.id,nacionales.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, nacionales WHERE vistas.id_pag = nacionales.id AND vistas.seccion = nacionales.tabla
UNION  SELECT regionales.id,regionales.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, regionales WHERE vistas.id_pag = regionales.id AND vistas.seccion = regionales.tabla
UNION  SELECT politica.id,politica.titulo,vistas.cuenta FROM vistas, politica WHERE vistas.id_pag = politica.id AND vistas.seccion = politica.tabla
) a
ORDER BY
cuenta DESC
```

Comment: That was it, Thanks a lot @oezi, I tried that before but it didn't work and I can see why, only one doubt, what is the " ) a" at the end of the parentheses for?

Comment: @SamRamSan: Alias for the subquery needs a name.

Comment: OK, Ok, ok... a se, excellent, incredible simple and yet, quite smart :-)

Answer (score -3):

You can't use `ORDER BY` when using `UNION`

Comment: just plain wrong. i't perfectly possible to order a `UNION`-query.